# How can I delete a conversation?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to quickly delete a conversation in Outlook 2010?

- The **Ignore** option will delete all future messages, which is definitely not what I want.
- The **Find Related** `->` **Messages In This Conversation** is slow and I have to press delete on the messages that come up several times before it takes (and it also takes me out of the flow of what I'm doing).

Note: I don't have conversation view turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting the conversation header and pressing delete does not simply remove the current messages?

If not it appears MS only gives you two ways to clean/remove conversations, either using the clean up function, which removes duplicate info and keeps only unique information, or the ignore function, which sends all messages from that conversation, past, present, and future, into the trash (where they can be recovered later if you want).

Otherwise, you should be able to group as a conversation, highlight the desired messages, and then press Delete to remove the selected messages.

UPDATE for additional information from OP:

In an exhaustive search of all possible Outlook 2010 buttons/options, I did not find any options that correspond to what the OP wants. MS appears to have assumed that when using Conversation tools, the user will generally be in the Conversation view, in which case the solution would simply be to select the entire conversation and press the Delete key.

Absent using the Conversation view Outlook does not offer a function that will automatically delete all current messages in a Conversation without either using the "cleanup" function or the "ignore" function.

However, due to Outlook's extensibility, something like this shouldn't be too difficult to program as an add-in or plug-in for someone familiar with such programming.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm not in conversation view, I'll fix my question.

Comment: Hmmm, so you essentially want a right-click or button option that will remove all messages conversation-related to a selected message while not in the conversation view?

Comment: yep, if possible :) i'm not a fan of conversation view, but some conversation tools would be nice

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the newest email in the conversation.  On the keyboard, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Outlook 2010 will display a message box.

> The selected conversation and all future messages will be moved to the Deleted Items folder.

Click the Ignore Conversation button.  That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently reading a message within a conversation, then
1.  Click on the left arrow to collapse the conversation and immediately Outlook will highlight the conversation
2.  Press the Delete button.